# Application layer silences SQL transaction error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a stored procedure

```
create proc spInsertRole
@rolename varchar(50)
as
begin
    set nocount on
    begin try
    begin tran
        if len(@roleName) > 15
            Raiserror('Role name is too long',1,5)
        insert into webpages_Roles(RoleName)
        values (@roleName)
        commit tran
        end try
    begin catch
        select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage
    rollback tran
    end catch
end
```

If I'm in SSMS and I try to add a role that's longer than 15 characters, this code will prevent that from happening and give me an error message `Role name is too long`

When I use the following C#, this code will allow the record to be added to the database.  I need to know why the C# SqlTransaction supersedes the SQL Server one, and where would I put the check for `roleName.Length > 15` in the C# code to present the user with an error that there role name is too long (this is in an MVC application).

```
public void InsertRole(string roleName)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlTransaction transaction;
                transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spInsertRole", con, transaction);
                try
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roleName", roleName);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                //how to throw this to the UI in MVC?
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                    catch (Exception rollBackException)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: you should keep this kind of validation in application layer rather than in SQL. another thing because you implement this check in at he very last step just before insert, you let the incorrect value pass through multiple layers. for example you defined SP parameter with VARCHAR(50). Ideally while user entering the Role Name, on the Client side only you should check the length.

Comment: @AnupShah I would like to keep server-side validation as well just in case they have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: You should not use transactions in both application code and in your stored procedures.

Comment: Because the @trancount has a good chance of being not correctly incremented/decremented when using both, leading to a multitude of problems during rollback in application code.

Comment: Actually, it's very cosistently updated: begin tran increments by one, commit decrements by one, and rollback sets it to zero. It's one of the most fundamental things.

Comment: However, if you encounter a staggered BEGIN TRAN and ROLLBACK TRAN edge case scenario in your sp's the application code cant recover. By the way I am referring to using begin transaction in application code that calls a stored procedure that also creates transactions with rollbacks.

Comment: Respect your opinion and agree that proper error handling and transaction management is not an easy topic to grasp. I'd really like to further discuss with you a scenario you're talking about. Unfortunatelly, comments here are not the proper format to get into this kind of discussion, so let's leave it be unless you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're using RAISERROR with severity 1, but severity of 10 or lower doesn't transfer control to CATCH block, it just prints the error message. Use higher severity.

Compare this code snipet:

```
declare @rolename varchar(50) = '123456789123456789'
begin try
    begin tran
    if len(@roleName) > 15
        Raiserror('Role name is too long',1,5)
    print 'inserting...'
    insert into webpages_Roles(RoleName)
    values (@roleName)
    print 'committing...'
    commit tran
end try
begin catch
    print 'catch'
    select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage
    print 'rolling back...'
    rollback tran
end catch
```

With this one:

```
declare @rolename varchar(50) = '123456789123456789'
begin try
    begin tran
    if len(@roleName) > 15
        Raiserror('Role name is too long',11,5)
    print 'inserting...'
    insert into webpages_Roles(RoleName)
    values (@roleName)
    print 'committing...'
    commit tran
end try
begin catch
    print 'catch'
    select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage
    print 'rolling back...'
    rollback tran
end catch
```

First one uses severity 1 and the control is not transfered to CATCH block; the other one uses severity 11, and does end up in CATCH.